# local variable return shows error message

Tags: python, function, variables, return, local

I think this is not a new question, but I think it's odd to show this message - local variable **df_ret** referenced before assignment - here is my function to recalculate imbalanced data set:

```
def down_sample(df, target, positive_label, negative_label):
    positives = df.filter(df[target] == positive_label)
    negatives = df.filter(df[target] == negative_label)
    num_positives = positives.count()
    num_negatives = negatives.count() 
    if (num_positives > num_negatives): # down_sample positives
        sampled_df = positives.sample(withReplacement=False, 
        fraction=num_negatives/num_positives, 
        seed=SEED)
        df_ret = sampled_df.union(negatives)

    return df_ret
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message "local variable df_ret referenced before assignment" is quite accurate here – the function ran and the `if` condition of `num_positives > num_negatives` was not true, so the code in the `if` block was never run, and hence the `df_ret` variable was never assigned (was never declared & initialized).

There are several  patterns you could use to fix this, depending on the expectations of the client(s) of this function:

- throw an exception within the function if the `if` condition is not satisfied, then have the caller `catch` the exception
- initialize the `df_ret` variable before the `if` block, so that the function return a default value when the `if` condition is not satisfied

Answer (score 0):

Great answer from gladiesgoodluck, I would also add a quick fix, which is to further indent the `return` command such that it only executes when the `if` condition is met.
your code would become:

```
def down_sample(df, target, positive_label, negative_label):
positives = df.filter(df[target] == positive_label)
negatives = df.filter(df[target] == negative_label)
num_positives = positives.count()
num_negatives = negatives.count() 
if (num_positives > num_negatives): # down_sample positives
    sampled_df = positives.sample(withReplacement=False, 
    fraction=num_negatives/num_positives, 
    seed=SEED)
    df_ret = sampled_df.union(negatives)

    return df_ret
return something_else  # OPTIONAL
```

Comment: Much appreciated. - I got it now.